# In an ember component template how can I use 'if' to check for at least one of an array having a property equal to X?

Tags: ember.js

My component is passed a `notification`.

A notification has an `account`, and an account has many `contacts`.

So I could easily do something like

```
{{#if (is-greater-than notification.account.contacts.length 0)}}
  <p>stuff</p>
{{/if}}
```

To check for the existence of a contact, but what if I wanted to only display if at least one contact has `firstName` 'John', how could I do this in the component template only? Or if not possible in the template what is the next best approach?

I tried having a isHidden property in my component and then in the didInsertElement hook looping through contacts and then communications with the aim of checking myself - however I find `contact.get('communications').forEach` doesn't get hit because that level of data hasn't been pulled from the server at that point.

Comment: Your second question is a bit orthogonal to this one. Could you remove the second question from this and move it to its own question? The answers aren't really similar in any way so it would be best to split them up.

Comment: Makes sense, I've written a second question for a nested 'has-any' helper function here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31459209/how-can-i-force-ember-to-get-into-the-second-level-of-an-object-in-a-template-us. The main issue is the promises arent resolved at the nested level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, you could write a helper to do that:

```
// helpers/contains-john.js
export default function(array) {
    return array.any((item) => item.get('firstName') === 'John');
};
```

Then use it as a subexpression just like you have above:

```
{{#if (contains-john notification.account.contacts)}}
    Stuff
{{/if}}
```