# How can I force Ember to get into the second level of an object in a template using a helper function?

Tags: ember.js

I have a 'has-many' helper (thanks to the help of @GJK in [In an ember component template how can I use 'if' to check for at least one of an array having a property equal to X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31456016/in-an-ember-component-template-how-can-i-use-if-to-check-for-at-least-one-of-a)) that allows me to check one level of an array in my template for a match on a property:

```
helpers/has-many.js

import Ember from 'ember';

// Param[0]: Array to iterate over
// Param[1]: Comparison operator to use, currently supports '===', '>', '<' and nested 'has-any'
// Param[2]: Value to check for
// (Optional) Param[3]: The property of the arrayObject to check, if this is not supplied the element of the array is checked directly

// Returns: True if array has at least one match to value

export function hasAny(params) {
console.log(params);
  var compare = function(a, b, operator) {
    console.log(a + ' ' + b + ' ' + operator);
    if (operator === '===') {
      return a === b;
    }
    if (operator === '>') {
      return a > b;
    }
    if (operator === '<') {
      return a < b;
    }

    return false;
  };

  if (params.length < 3) {
    return false;
  }

  if (params[0] === undefined || params[1] === undefined || params[2] === undefined) {
    return false;
  }

  if (params.length === 3) {
    return params[0].any((item) => compare(item, params[2], params[1]));
  }

  if (params[3] === undefined) {
    return false;
  }

  return params[0].any((item) => compare(item.get(params[3]), params[2],     params[1]));

}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(hasAny);
```

I now want to add a second level to this so that I can do the equivalent of

```
notification.account.contacts.Any(c => c.communications.Any(cm => cm.communicationType.description === 'Email'));
```

I tried adding to my code with the following:

helpers/has-many.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

// Param[0]: Array to iterate over
// Param[1]: Comparison operator to use, currently supports '===', '>', '<' and nested 'has-any'
// Param[2]: Value to check for
// (Optional) Param[3]: The property of the arrayObject to check, if this is not supplied the element of the array is checked directly

// Returns: True if array has at least one match to value

export function hasAny(params) {
console.log(params);
  var compare = function(a, b, operator) {
    console.log(a + ' ' + b + ' ' + operator);
    if (operator === '===') {
      return a === b;
    }
    if (operator === '>') {
      return a > b;
    }
    if (operator === '<') {
      return a < b;
    }
    if (operator.lastIndexOf('has', 0) === 0) {
      var innerParams = operator.split('%');
      console.log(a);
      return hasAny(a, innerParams[1], innerParams[2], b);
    }
    return false;
  };

  if (params.length < 3) {
    return false;
  }

  if (params[0] === undefined || params[1] === undefined || params[2] === undefined) {
    return false;
  }

  if (params.length === 3) {
    return params[0].any((item) => compare(item, params[2], params[1]));
  }

  if (params[3] === undefined) {
    return false;
  }

  return params[0].any((item) => compare(item.get(params[3]), params[2],     params[1]));

}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(hasAny);
```

And then in the template I have:

```
{{#if (has-any notification.account.contacts 'has-any%===%Email' 'communicationType.description' 'communications')}}
  <p>working!</p>
{{/if}}
```

The problem I have is although the template knows to fire the helper again once notification.account.contacts has resolved from the API, it doesnt know to go again once each contacts' communications have come down from the API - how can I force the template/helper to get my next level of promises?

---

**EDIT 1**
These are the models (slightly stripped down, but with the key fields):

models/order-notification.js

```
Export default DS.Model.extend({
  orderNotificationType: DS.belongsTo('orderNotificationType', {async: true}),
  orderNotificationDetail: DS.attr('string'),
  sent: DS.attr('boolean'),
  account: DS.belongsTo('account', {async: true}),
});
```

models/account.js

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  accountType: DS.hasMany('accountType', {async: true}),
  contacts: DS.hasMany('contact', {async: true}),
  addresses: DS.hasMany('address', {async: true}),
});
```

models/contact.js

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string'),
  accounts: DS.hasMany('account', {async: true}),
  communications: DS.hasMany('communication', {async: true})
});
```

models/communication.js

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  value: DS.attr('string'),
  communicationType: DS.belongsTo('communicationType', {async: true}),
  contact: DS.belongsTo('contact', {async: true})
});
```

models/communication-type.js

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  communications: DS.hasMany('communication', {async: true})
});
```

---

**EDIT 2**

I've got something nearly working:

```
{{#each notification.account.contacts as |contact index|}}
  {{#each contact.communications as |communication id|}}
    {{#if (has-any contact.communications '===' 'Email' 'communicationType.description' communication.communicationType.description)}}
    <p>Working!</p>
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

By going within the each and passing a fourth parameter to the has-any helper (that is unused), all the promises are resolved - the problem I have is that `<p>Working!</p>` comes up multiple times (because the any is satisfied multiple times by multiple contacts/communications). This method could work if there is a way within an #each to display the contents of an if block only the first time the if is satisfied.

Comment: I'm at work now, so I unfortunately don't have the time to answer this. But I think I know the solution, so hopefully I'll have some time later tonight to get back to you (if nobody else does in the meantime).

Comment: Thanks @GJK, if you don't have time for a full answer than some hints to what your thinking may get me far enough to right one up.

Comment: I don't think I have an answer for this one (yet). :/ The problem you're having is the nested observers (or promises), which is often a pain to deal with. Unfortunately, as mentioned [here](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/), nested `@each` observers do not work but that's exactly what you need. I've gotten around this a few times, but it depends on your object model really. Would you mind posting the models you're working with? (Side note: I'm not sure if it's going to be possible without adding computed properties to your models.)

Comment: Ok, i've gone ahead and added those

Comment: I also added a second edit with one further idea..

Comment: You're trying to turn Handlebars into a place to do business logic, which is both a bad idea and also flies in the face of the original philosophy of Handlebars, which is, in a word, "you get your 'stuff' ready, then I pump it out". With this approach, you have yet another place to do more computations, manipulations, filtering, sorting, and aggregating, in addition to whatever you're already doing on the server, in your model, or in your controller. Keep your templates nice and clean and readable, Put logic in the controller or the `component.js`.

Comment: Thanks @torazaburo I will certainly bear this in mind. TBH i'd love to be doing this in the controller or component js but because of Ember's nested each restriction in the observables I've had to use the model to house some logic sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I couldn't do this the way I wanted to but GLK got me in the right direction. At the very lowest layer I aliased communicationType.description in the communication model:

```
communicationTypeDescription: Ember.computed.alias('communicationType.description')
```

I then observe that in a property at the next level up

```
communicationsAvailable: function() {
  var commsAvailable = [];
  this.get('communications').forEach(function(comm) {
    commsAvailable.push(comm.get('communicationType.description'));
  });
  return commsAvailable.filter(function(value, index, ca) {
    return ca.indexOf(value) === index;
  });
}.property('communications.@each.communicationTypeDescription')
```

I then observe that observable at the next layer up (you could repeat this bit for however deep you need), in my account model:

```
communicationsAvailable: function() {
  var commsAvailable = [];
  this.get('contacts').forEach(function(contact) {
    commsAvailable.push.apply(commsAvailable, contact.get('communicationsAvailable'));
  });
  return commsAvailable.filter(function(value, index, ca) {
    return ca.indexOf(value) === index;
  });
}.property('contacts.@each.communicationsAvailable')
```

Note the subtle difference here of `push.apply`.

Finally, I then used my has-many function in it's 3 param form in my template:

```
{{#if (has-any notification.account.communicationsAvailable '===' 'Email')}}
  <p>Working!</p>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Sorry that I couldn't answer, I was on vacation this week. Glad you got it working though. This is essentially what I had to do when I ran into similar issues. Another possible solution: sideload all of your records at the same time so that all of the relationships are populated after the first wave of observers fire. That method isn't quite as versatile and is a little more prone to bugs, but it can really help out in a pinch (especially if you've got some funky domain logic like we did).

Comment: Thanks, once our backend work catches up I am hoping we can get some sideloading going on. I must admit I'm really disappointed with the above approach being the best available with Ember. Our application is going to big so filling our models with bloat like this annoys me somewhat.

Comment: I've recently begun using a [Flux architecture](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html) since we started using React at my new job. While there are pros and cons of both approaches, I find that Flux is better when it comes to crazy data updates (like what you have here). You might want to read about it a bit and see if there's any room for it in your application. (You don't have to do everything in Flux, you can take ideas and apply them to your current scenario as needed.)